# Array Index out of Bounds, not sure what's going on (JAVA)

Tags: java

Hi guys im working on an anagram detector in any passage.

I have a problem with the array index out of bounds exception, im pretty sure the array positions and their memory locations are generated run time, there is no interference by the user.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
class never {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
        int[] array1 = new int[100];
        int[] checker = {
            121, 97, 104, 101, 97, 100, 104, 105, 109, 63, 32
        };
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        String str = input.toLowerCase();
        String str1 = input.replaceAll("\\W", " ");
        String[] name1 = new String[5000];
        name1 = str1.split(" ");
        int length = name1.length;
        System.out.println(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (name1[i] == " ") {
                name1[i] = name1[i + 1];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
                Boolean s1 = name1[i].equals(name1[j]);
                if (s1 == true) {
                    name1[j] = " ";
                }
                if (name1[i] == " ") {
                    name1[i] = name1[j];
                    name1[j] = " ";
                }
            }
        }
        length = name1.length;
        System.out.println(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < name1[i].length(); j++) {
                char charz = name1[i].charAt(j);
                int iz = (int) charz;
                for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++) {
                    if (iz == checker[k]) {
                        length--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) //Problem lies here
        {
            name1[i] = name1[i].toLowerCase();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
                int counter = 0;
                char[] arr1 = name1[i].toCharArray();
                char[] arr2 = name1[j].toCharArray();
                java.util.Arrays.sort(arr1);
                java.util.Arrays.sort(arr2);
                int arraylen;
                if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
                    continue;
                } else arraylen = arr1.length;
                for (int k = 0; k < arraylen; k++) {
                    if (arr1[i] == arr2[i]) {
                        counter = counter + 1;
                        if (counter == arraylen) {
                            System.out.println(name1[i] + "  " + name1[j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you only post the relevant portions of the code?

Comment: We need the stacktrace...

Comment: Which line specifically, in which of your multiple nested loops is causing the exception?

Comment: are you sure this is ok?: `name1[i]=name1[i+1];`

Comment: You are checking for equality using `==` with string, which is not okay. `==` checks for object (memory) equality, not equivalence. Use `str1.equals(str2)`

Comment: Above the line throwing the exception, add a System.out.println printing out _all_ variables in the exception throwing line one by one .  Then run again and look at the values printed out, and find out what is wrong with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index out of bounds exception means that you are trying to access a index that doesn't exists.

Say that you have an array with 9 elements. array[9] will be the 10th and it wont exists.

Comment: Thanks, used a different index by mistake

Comment: No matter how much experience you have you'll always get that problem once in a while. Glad I could help.